# why i am getting Input MIsmatch Exception in this code?

Tags: java, string

I am just trying to read integer, double , string values from keyboard.
it just working fine for integer and double. but when it comes to string, it was throwing a Input Mismatch Exception, so i cant able to read string from keyboard.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d= scan.nextInt();
        String s=scan.nextLine();

        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: String s=scan.next();

Comment: @user158302 can you tell me why you import the Scanner class separately??

Comment: "but when it comes to string, it was throwing a Input Mismatch Exception," is very had to believe since string can represent any characters provided by users so it shouldn't be mismatched. Other problem is that `nextLine()` most likely will return empty string (see [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13102045) for more details).

Comment: Anyway to get proper answers we need to [edit] your question and provide proper [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)) which aside from code also should include input you used while running your code and *exact* error message you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You have used 
`double d= scan.nextInt();`

instead use

`double d= scan.nextDouble();`

Moreover String is working fine for following input and output:
1 1 Hello

String:  Hello

Double: 1.0

Int: 1

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the object type since the result of the input is promoted automagically to `double`.

Comment: 1 1.0 Hello                                              
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException

Answer (score 0):

First, you're doing a `scan.nextInt()` for a double.  Not the best thing to do.  Second, try `scan.next()` to get an arbitrary type token.

```
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        double d= scan.nextDouble();
        String s=scan.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

please check the below code. it is working for me.

```
      public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter i value ");
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter d value ");
        double d= scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter s value ");
        String s=scan.next();


        // Write your code here.

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `String s=scan.nextLine();` consumes the newline character coming from the followed calling `double d= scan.nextInt();`.

Here is my two cents.

```
double d = scan.nextInt();
scan.nextLine();
String s = scan.nextLine();
```